# Initiate Header Once and Send in Every HTTP Request

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api

I am using a service to get user ids in HTML `DropDownList` and it works fine. Here am using an `Angular` service to get the user details and for back-end, `ASP.NET Web Api`. So far this is what I've done so far:

**Web Api - C#**:

```
[Route("api/values/GetUserInfo")]
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public List<User> GetUserInfo(string type)
{
   List<User> lst = null;

   if (type!= null)
   {
       lst = GetUserInfo().Where(c => c.userType== type).ToList();
   }
   else
   {
       lst = GetUserInfo().ToList();
   }

   return lst;
}
```

**Angular: Service - UserService**

```
GetUserInfo(dept: string) {
   debugger;

   this.Url = 'http://localhost:53743/api/values/';
   var a = this.Url + 'GetUserInfo';

   var headers_object = new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('Token')); //Set JWT Token 

   let params = new HttpParams().set("type", type);

   return this.http.get<any>(a, { headers: headers_object, params: params }); //Get request to retrieve the user details from database server
}
```

Finally in the **Angular Component**:

```
public empIds: any[];

constructor(private dataservice: UserService, private appComponent: AppComponent, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer, private route: Router, private http: HttpClient) { //UserService injected in the constructor

}

ngOnInit() {
   this.LoadUserData('');
}

LoadUserData(dept: string) {
   debugger;
   this.dataservice.GetUserInfo(dept).subscribe(result => { //Calling the `Angular` service here
   this.empIds = result; //Keeping the result set here
  }, error => console.error(error));
}
```

So far, these are my done work and was wondering if I can manage the header initiated once in every `HTTP` request. Like a class that handles all the post and get request and I did some research on it searching goggle but bit confused how could I make it work accordingly? Below is what I've been studying so far and trying to implement in my code sample. But the issue is when there are parameters how I could handle them with the following code sample.

**Angular - httpService**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class HttpClientService { 

  value: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  createAuthorizationHeader(headers: HttpHeaders) {
    //headers.append('content-type', 'application/json');
    //headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('Token'));
  }

  get(url, value, type) {
    debugger;
    let params = new HttpParams().set("dept", dept);
    var headers_object = new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", "Bearer " + value);

    const httpOptions = {
      headers: headers_object
    };

    return this.http.get<any>(url, {
      headers: headers_object, params: params
    });
  }

  post(url, data, value) {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    let headers_object = new HttpHeaders();
    headers_object.append('content-type', 'application/json');
    headers_object.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + value);

    //this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
    return this.http.post<any>(url, data, {
      headers: headers_object, params: params
    });
  }
}
```

As an example below in the component:

```
this.httpService.get(a, localStorage.getItem('Token'), dept).subscribe(result => {
    this.empIds = result;
}, error => console.error(error));
```

**N.B**: I am almost novice to `Angular` and it's working flow, trying to figure out the things in a better way - Thanks.

Comment: Read this: https://angular.io/guide/http#set-default-headers. An interceptor is what you're looking for. More info: https://angular.io/guide/http#http-interceptors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `interceptor`.

If you want to add the specific headers in every request you have to do like the following : (**Here I add Accept Header in every http request**)

```
@Injectable()
export class ExampleAuth implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):
    Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json') }); // Here you can add your special headers 

    return next.handle(request);
  }

}
```

then add the interceptor in the provider section of your app module as below :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ExampleAuth, multi: true }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Now whenever a new HTTP request will be made, this Interceptor will modify the Headers of request.

**More Explanations:**

Angular Interceptor is a powerful feature which can be used in many ways for securing and handling many HTTP related phenomena.

***What we can do using Interceptors?***

Interceptors can be used in a number of ways in an application.

– Set request headers in HTTP calls like Content-Type or send any custom headers.

– Authenticate HTTP calls by setting Security tokens

– Show Spin Loaders/ Progress Bars as HTTPS calls are in progress.

– Handle Errors in HTTP calls at one place

– Show Response messages using Notifications/ Toasts

**EDIT:**

According to your example,In your HttpClientService , you have to remove the following lines because they will add automatically to the http request headers in the interceptor:

```
var headers_object = new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", "Bearer " + value);
 headers_object.append('content-type', 'application/json');
```

Modify your HttpClientService as below:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class HttpClientService { 
  value: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  get(url, value, type) {
    debugger;
    let params = new HttpParams().set("dept", dept);

    const options = {
      params: params
    };
    return this.http.get<any>(url, options);
  }

  post(url, data, value) {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    const options = {
      params: params
    };
    return this.http.post<any>(url, data, options);
  }
}
```

Then in the Interceptor we have to add the headers that we have just removed from `HttpClientService`

```
@Injectable()
export class ExampleAuth implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):
    Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('content-type', 'application/json') }); 
    request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('Token') ) });

    return next.handle(request);
  }

}
```

Then register the interceptor in app module.

Comment: Thanks @AbolfazlR. Is it possible to provide an example with my code sample if you have time? Seems like lost a bit :D :D

Comment: @AT-2017- your welcome, I updated my answer , If you have any problem let me know.

Comment: OK @AbolfazlR. I've to replace the code of the `httpService` with your given code and finally register in the app module, then how this thing should be called in the `Angular` services or component?

Comment: @AT-2017- You do not need to call it , It will call automatically before sending every http request . You must only register it in app.module .

Comment: I appreciate your time and effort @ AbolfazlR. Hoping this is the last time I am asking. So should I remove the header here, in the service - `return this.http.get<any>(a, { headers: headers_object, params: params }); //Get request to retrieve the user details from database server` and this is all I've to do?

Comment: @AT-2017 - I updated my answer , see Edit section .I hope it will remove your problem .finally If it do not remove your problem , make a stackblitz sample https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203531/discussion-between-abolfazlr-and-at-2017).

Comment: Thanks very much @AbolfazlR. Just made it work and accordinly, I'll update my post on this later.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) which can intercept all your requests you make and all their responses.

You can thus also use it to display consistent error messages on each failed request.

You can have a look at [Angular's documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses) to see how to implement it.

The example the give is very similar to what you need:

```
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    // Get the auth token from the service.
    const authToken = this.auth.getAuthorizationToken();

    // Clone the request and replace the original headers with
    // cloned headers, updated with the authorization.
    const authReq = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', authToken)
    });

    // send cloned request with header to the next handler.
    return next.handle(authReq);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @C.Champagne. Could you provide an example with my sample code if you have time? Seems like lost a bit :D :D